# In JIRA, how can I create an issue filter that excludes duplicates?

Tags: jira, jql

I have a JIRA issue filter in which I list a set of issues that meet my criteria. Some of these have links of type duplicates. I want to exclude those duplicates issues from my query.

Logically I am looking for something like:

`...
AND ! hasLinks('duplicates')`

I believe this functionality is in the [JQL Tricks Plugin](http://www.j-tricks.com/jql-tricks-plugin.html), but this plug-in is pretty pricey.

Is there any way to do this natively with JQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA050/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-CONTAINS:~

The "~" operator is used to search for issues where the value of the specified field matches the specified valu

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see a way to get this to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the issue has status Closed with resolution Duplicate, try this filter:

```
 ... and (resolution is empty or resolution != Duplicate)
```